# Python/Selenium trying to use an "if" statement on an element when not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, automation

I'm trying to raise ValueError with specific message when xpath is not found.

```
@step('Click save')
def step_impl(context):

click_save = 
context.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='save_button']")
if not click_save:
   raise ValueError('Save button is not found')
click_save.click()
```

Ideally I would like for the raise ValueError to display if the save button is not found... but the code will never get to the "if" statement when the click_save xpath is not found. I would just get an error ...blah blah xpath not found or whatever it is.

I'm trying to do this to be more specific when in a group of tests you may have similar xpaths and I want to know exactly which one failed.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium unable to find the element and thrown the error. You could check the length count of the element and if it zero it should raise error.

Try the below code.

```
if len(browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@class='save_button']"))==0:
   raise ValueError('Save button is not found')
else:
  click_save = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='save_button']")
  click_save.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is coming because selenium is unable to identify the xpath of the given element and generate exception there.

What you can do is, you can keep your code in a try/catch block and then execute your code.

Answer (score 0):

I would not generate the errors unnecessarily, rather I would get the count of matching elements and compare the len as shown below.

```
@step('Click save')
def step_impl(context):

    numberOFSaveElems = len(context.browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@class='save_button']"))
    if numberOfSaveElems==0:
        raise ValueError('Save button is not found')
    click_save.click()
```